# Mysql how to extract stored JSON value

Tags: php, mysql, json

How do I extract a value stored in a field as json. The customerId is currently stored in the juniferResponse field like {"customerId":1}

The follow does not work in the version of mysql I am using:

```
SELECT json_extract(juniferResponse, '$.customerId') AS cid FROM enrolment WHERE juniferResponse IS_NOT_NULL;
```

I need to extract the value from the juniferResponse where the field is not null or empty.

Comment: is `juniferResponse` as json string ?

Comment: I think I don't get your questing as I look at this code you are going to do something like `SELECT 1 AS cid FROM enrolment WHERE juniferResponse IS_NOT_NULL;` which doesn't make sense to me ...

Comment: if you don't need to perform an aggregation, or where condition on the result, you could just extract the json in PHP json_decode($row['juniferResponse'], true) // will extract as array

Comment: juniferResponse is the name of the column and it has a stored value like {"customerId":1} I need to get the 1 which is the id where the column is not empty.

Comment: @DanIonescu I would rather do it in the query as I have to update a large db.

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to do?, i see just a select in your post

Comment: This shouls work. Post some sample rows please

Comment: @DanIonescu At this stage I just want to extract the customer id as value not the entire json string. So i would extract the 1 from {"customerId":1}

Comment: @user794846 i've offered a solution based on MID and  LOCATE string operators below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't upgrate MySQL to 5.7.8 or higer.
It is possible to use the select below:

```
SET @a='{"z":"\\"customerId\\"","customerId":41,"a":1,"b2":2}';

SELECT IF(LOCATE('"customerId":',@a)>0,1*substring(@a,LOCATE('"customerId":',@a)+13),NULL);
```

The select returns NULL if the customerId key does not exist

```
13 is the number of letters in the locate string ["customerId":]
```

OR create the function like below. Which is more useful

```
DELIMITER  //
CREATE FUNCTION json_extract_int (jstring TEXT,jkey CHAR(20))
RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
SET jkey = CONCAT('"',jkey,'":');
RETURN IF(LOCATE(jkey,jstring)>0,1*substring(jstring,LOCATE(jkey,jstring)+LENGTH(jkey)),NULL);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Now it is easy to use

```
SELECT json_extract_int(@a,'customerId');
+-----------------------------------+
| json_extract_int(@a,'customerId') |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                41 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

OR in your case

```
SELECT json_extract_int(juniferResponse,'customerId');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can't upgrade your mysql server to work with json_extract, and you can't use json_decode in your application you could use MID and LOCATE.
But your json will have to be like be like {"some_key":some_number} 
you could use the following query:

```
SELECT 
MID(
    juniferResponse, 
    LOCATE(':', juniferResponse) + 1, 
    LOCATE('}', juniferResponse) - LOCATE(':', juniferResponse) - 1 
    ) AS cid
FROM `exam`
WHERE juniferResponse IS NOT NULL
```